# How to set up Linux AD Authentication to Trusted Domain

Tags: active-directory, centos7, trust-relationship

I have successfully joined a CentOS 7 server to a Windows Server 2012R2 domain: `domain1.local`. This domain hosts test server objects that we've created for experimentation.

`domain1.local` is the trusting party to another Windows Server 2012R2 domain: `ent.com` The Trust Type is "Forest" and it is transitive.

For Windows servers, users in `ent.com` can access objects in `domain1.local` without any sort of problem. My CentOS server authenticate users in `ent.com`, though.

I joined the `domain1.local` domain on CentOS as follows:

`realm join -U 'administrator@DOMAIN1.LOCAL' -v` and am able to get information for users and groups that exist in `DOMAIN1.LOCAL` using things like `id` and `kinit`.

My assumption is that it has something to do with the way the trust is set up and how I've joined my CentOS server to the domain, but I'm not exactly sure what I need to do.

Comment: It sounds like you only have a one way trust between the domains, where a two way trust would be required for this to work.